# boost LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I read through the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/index.html) using the '5.3.4   Invoke b2' and followed up with forum threads that explained details of linking the boost library to the [header and linker directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174519/how-to-include-boostthread-in-your-c-project), in the boost help '4.1   Build From the Visual Studio IDE', and found this cool boost related wiki that explained the [bjam.exe controls](http://wiki.thedarkmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_the_static_Boost_Libraries_in_Windows).

placed `#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>` in the main.cpp

And, I get this linker error, and the existing help threads have identified the problem is with x64:

- [Directory path and x32/x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714660/linker-error-lnk2019-when-linking-boost-1-51-0-dynamically-in-vs2010)
- [unrelated to Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487646/linking-to-boost-through-sconstruct)
- [unresolved](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-dev/s2b_aSLm3R4/VqekND9wf6gJ)

The error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'posix_category''(void)" (??__Eposix_category@system@boost@@YAXXZ)  main.obj

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)  main.obj
```

they are similar, something about `'posix_category'` and something about `'native_ecat'`

So, I tried to build the x64 boost library, and found conflicting instructions on where to put these:

- did not say ["Note for x64 users: Add the address-model=64 option to bjam (after the threading argument) in order to build static libs with the 64-bit compiler."](http://wiki.thedarkmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_the_static_Boost_Libraries_in_Windows)
- cant find the link but one said to place x64 lib in the vs2008 bin?

Also, I tried changing the vs2008 configuration back to x32 -> solutionExplorer/solution_properties/configuration_manager/active_solution_platform - Win32, closed and reopened visual studio - relinked the additional directories C/C++/general and Linker/general to Boost/root and Boost/stage/lib - and it compiled without error.

My best guess at the b2 commands is `--toolset=msvc-9.0 address-model=64 --build-type=complete --stagedir=lib\x64 stage`

Please give concise instructions for how to build and install x64 version of boost on VS2008. Also, what was the wiki talking about for release and debug - they are not in [Boost invocation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html)?

Comment: Any reason you are using 5.3 from the installation instructions instead of "5.2 Simplified Build From Source" ?

Comment: @us2012 nothing specific - i saw that but was not sure what it is, it is preceded with "5.1   Install Visual Studio Binaries" and talks about "BoostPro Computing" who are no longer producing installs, so i probably skipped over it and went for what looked like most help threads I'd read about bjam.exe - fair enough...

Comment: I'm not saying that it will solve your problem, but since it's fully automated and super-easy to use, I suggest you at least try it.

Comment: yes, but it is the super automated and super easy part that has me worried. I have VS 2005, 2010, and a beta 2011 installed that in earlier installs caused the automated and easy approach to become complicated and convoluted :)

Comment: I encountered this issue while using the boost auto-linking, and fixed it by adding #include <../boost_libs.h>

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use c++ 11

It more or less includes all the features of boost I wanted to use, also compiles in g++ without figuring out how to build the boost library on my university server and then reference into a remote g++ build - pretty much solved everything with that

Comment: The C++11 standard library is not a complete replacement for Boost. Besides, most of the Boost libraries are header-only and don't need you to compile anything up-front at all, those who aren't seldom depend on other libraries so you can just copy their sources and compile them with a proper build tool, see for example https://github.com/filmor/webos-pdf.

Comment: I am was using boost::thread and after two days could not figure out how to get the library in the g++ build - and even if I did there is a bug in the 6.4 version of RedHat - c++ 11 worked. My advice to anyone else in the same situation is to use c++ 11. Also, your link does not go to anything.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the bug in Red Hat? Besides, this question is evidently about Windows so it's a completely different situation. The link I've given goes to a project of mine where I integrated the  Boost.Thread library, where it suffices to add 4 source files (see https://github.com/filmor/webos-pdf/tree/master/boost_thread).

Comment: you are correct - I asked this question about win but it was part of a larger effort for a version in linux, which apparently would have failed even if I resolved the question with the x64 library. I should not have mentioned it in this thread - I also posted a question on our University email discussion and was warned that "In case this is on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4, there is a new bug introduced in 6.4 with boost thread libraries and the gcc/g++ version in stock 6.4: Red Hat Bugzilla Bug 908774" I am happy with the c++ 11 thread solution but now understand how your solution would work